# SSIS : How to use System variable in a like condition

Tags: ssis

I am trying to get the job name based on package name but get stuck on how to use the system variable in like condition.

I tried to store the value in Parameter (input) and pass it as ? but it takes ? instead of package name.

```
SELECT sj.name as JobName
,s.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON s.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE s.subsystem = 'SSIS' and s.command like '%@System::PackageName%';
```

Your help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next please write question with more detail. If i understand you well, your query be like:

```
"SELECT sj.name as JobName
,s.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON s.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE s.subsystem = 'SSIS' and s.command like '%" + @[System::PackageName] + "%'"
```

You can try also [this tutorial](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/) under **Use the Variable in a SQL Statement** section.

If I missed something write me in comment and i will try to help you again.